# Problems passing data to view using PRADO

Tags: php, model-view-controller, prado

I've been given a website to maintain. The website is using PRADO framework and I had to do some minor changes. There were no problems with the HTML and CSS changes, but now I have to pass some data from a page to a view.
I've tried using:

```
$this->HomeCalendar2->DataSource = $result['data'];
$this->HomeCalendar2->dataBind();
```

but it says `Component property 'Home.HomeCalendar2' is not defined.`

Above my code there is the following code:

```
$this->HomeCalendar->DataSource = $result;
$this->HomeCalendar->dataBind();
```

and it works perfectly fine and I can't see where is the definition of HomeCalendar.
Any help will be appreciated.

P.S: I've never worked with PRADO before.

Comment: Do you have a file named XXX.page XXX being the same name as the file including the code above? Also you need to add component tags in this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is quite old now, hope you already solved it.

Using DataSource means that there must be in your template (.page or .tpl) a [TDataBoundControl](http://www.pradosoft.com/docs/manual/class-TDataBoundControl.html) component like the folowwing (using TRepeater for example)

```
<com:TRepeater ID="HomeCalendar">
<!--- [ properties like ItemTemplate here and it contents ] --->
</com:TRepeater>
```

Subclasses of TDataBoundControl are for component needing to loop results, (sorts of `for` or `foreach` somehow).
If you juste need to pass a signle result to the view you can use a component like TPanel/TActivePanel, TLiteral, etc. or simply use the [expression tag](http://www.pradosoft.com/demos/quickstart/?page=Configurations.Templates2#dct).

**Examples :**

Expression tag :

Php :

```
<?php
$this->myvalue = 'Hello World!';
```

Template :

```
<h1><%= $this->myvalue %></h1>
```

**Or another solution:**

Template :

```
<com:TLiteral ID="MyLiteral" />
```

PHP :

```
<?php
$this->MyLiteral->getControls()->add('<h1>Hello world !</h1>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have no idea if this solves the problem because I'm not working on this site for about an year and I have no idea how I solved the problem back then. I will still accept the answer :)